# Why Jquery datePicker not working on asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to use jquery datepicker provided in jquery-ui-1.10.4. But problem is that it is working fine for html input tag without server side.

As soon as I used it for server side the jquery function is not performing

Coded as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

and working piece is

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>//Without runat attribute
```

But when runat attribute is added it stop working

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server"/>//Without runat attribute
```

Anybody helps!!!

Comment: is it in master page?

Comment: what is the date format you send to datepicker?

Comment: @RashminJaviya it inside master page

Comment: @HassaanKhan please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to master page. when you use master page it append prefix "CPH" to each control in child pages. try accessing using class.

**Javascript**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" class="datepicker"/>
```

**HTML**

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

If you do not want to use class then second way is to use `$("#CPH_datepicker")` as a selector

Comment: The problem is that runat="server" was generating and id so i resolved it using ClientIdMode="Static" property

Comment: No, using "CPH_DatePicker" as your jQuery selector is a bad idea. It's not strongly typed, and it's based on an assumption of how the ID is generated (which could change). Instead, setting the ClientIdMode to Static or using inline expressions to retrieve the ID is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Server side controls automatically generate an ID based on the nesting hierarchy of being within master pages.

So this is an option:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```

Or this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= datepicker.ClientId %>").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

The second option is preferable, because it's strongly typed. Although with the first solution, you can also change the ClientIdMode at the page, web.config, or machine.config levels.